# Есть ли в этом отрывке ошибка,где если есть и как исправить?

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
float square( double number )
{
double number
return (float)number * number;}
```

Comment: Компилировать пробовали?  Объявление `double number`  второй раз, да еще без точки с запятой глаз не режет?

Answer (score 2):

Формальная?

```
double number
```

эта строка совершенно лишняя.

Но какой смысл в том, чтобы при входе `double` возвращать `float`?

Answer (score 2):

Объявление локальной переменной `double number` конфликтует с параметром с тем же именем. И написано без точки с запятой. Его надо убрать.

Выражение `(float)number * number` устроено как `float * double` - приведение применяется к первому аргументу. В [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) находим пункт:

> 2. Otherwise, if one operand is double, double complex, or double imaginary (since C99), the other operand is implicitly converted as follows:
>
>    - integer or real floating type to double

Перевод: если второй аргумент `double`, то и первый аргумент к нему приведётся.

То есть то что мы написали это `((double)(float)number) * number`. Привели `double` к `float` (потеряли точность), привели обратно.

И так как значение функции типа `float`, то всё выражение неявно приводится к `float`.

В общем получилось так:

```
float square(double number) {
    return number * number;
}
```

Но какой в этом смысл? Эта функция ничем не лучше (а иногда и хуже) чем

```
double square(double number) {
    return number * number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть примерно как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>


float square( double number );

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float result = square(2);
    printf("Result: %f\n", result);
    return 0;
}

float square( double number )
{
    return (float)number * number;
}
```

Comment: Кому должно и почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy Должно решению задачи. Потому, что так можно решить задачу. Код как в вопросе к сожалению не ведет нас к решению. И это печально.  Переменная `double number` уже существует в функции и еще раз объявлять ее в теле функции нет никакой необходимости.